# How can i call getCacheDir() from a Class that extends Fragment

Tags: android

I made a file through `class` that `extends Activity` and now I want to open this file from an other class that `extends Fragment`.

But apparently it's not possible to call `getCacheDir()` from a `class` that it's not extending `Activity`.. Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be accessed with `getActivity().getCacheDir()`

Comment: How to do it without Activity?

Comment: You have to pass a context via an activity or somewhere available. And then `context.getCacheDir()`